# missing some letters and number in textview in android 4.3+

Tags: android, textview, xamarin.android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I create a view like below image in my monodroid application with  code. While every thing is right when I test the app in android 4.1 but when I test it on the android 4.3 and 4.4.2 I faced with below screen. I do not test it on the android 4.2

In the textviews any numbers are not showing. It looks that I typed space. Also about some letters.
What is wrong?! What has been changed in the android 4.3 + ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like consistent characters are missing. You mentioned numbers, but I also notice that the letter 'a' and 'd' are always blanked out. I think you'll want to debug or print out the values before calling setText() to see what's getting set.

Also, check your data/strings xml and/or feeds for encoding. Maybe the characters aren't properly encoded?

Do you call String.replaceAll(regex) anywhere?

Does this happen on all 4.3+ devices, or just one that you've tested?

Comment: I tested it on the 2 4.3 device and one 4.4 device and all have not the letters and the numbers

Comment: What about encodings and debugger output? If you print out the text to the console in 4.3+, do the characters show up?

Comment: @Matt may you please specify about string.replace(regex). what that mean?

Comment: If you don't know what it means, you probably don't have any calls to it. I was wondering if you were doing any processing on the text, and maybe there's a slightly different implementation in 4.3+... You can just do a full-project search for "replace" and see if you're doing anything that might alter the behavior of these TextViews.

Comment: I load the data from web, the output of the wen is right. but maybe in the parsing on the 4.3 it faced with some error. Let me check it

Comment: Yes, I have some replace. I'm going to check both printout and replaces

Comment: When I print out the string value they are right. only they are not right in the screen

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45819/discussion-between-matt-and-husein-behbudirad)

Comment: @Matt, you was right. It is related to some changes in the display of text-view's in this activity. I add a shadow to them and this was the root cause. Thanks.Now you can add the idea as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Have the same issue on Nexus 5 with 4.4 android. What excactly helped you out if you are ready with the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is still space for the letters, so perhaps it's an issue with the styling.

Change the style to default, do the letters show up?

Try adding a shadow to the textviews and see if the shadow exists (maybe the letters are somehow transparent, or the same color as the background?)

Answer (score 0):

by referring to @ArieDov comment I post this answer:

Below method that I used caused the problem:

```
public static void AddShadowEffect (TextView textview)
    {
        try {
            if(RltXmlSettings.Instance.getVal ("shadow_enabled")=="1")
            {
              float[] direction = new float[] {0.3f, -1.0f, 0.0f};
              MaskFilter filter = new EmbossMaskFilter (direction, 0.8f, 15f, 5f);
              textview.Paint.SetMaskFilter (filter);
              textview.Invalidate ();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            RltLog.HandleException (ex);
        }
    }
```

the purpose of this method was adding the shadows you see in the question image. and I fixed the problem by changing the style of textviews just like what @Matt said. I used below code for my textviews:

```
txtlName.SetTypeface (null, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
```

and this fixed my problem.